# Use different peers for ingress and egress traffic

Tags: networking

All the following prices were invented for the sake of this question.

Let's say we have two peers:

- Peer 1, who charges us **1 cent per megabyte of transfer EGRESS**, and 1 dollar per megabyte of transfer INGRESS.
- Peer 2, who charges us 1 dollar per megabyte of transfer EGRESS, and **1 cent per megabyte of transfer INGRESS**

Clearly, we'd like to get the best of both world, **PEER 1** for outbound traffic, and **PEER 2** for inbound traffic.

I don't know very much, concerning networking, but is it possible to only use **PEER 1** for outbound, and **PEER 2** for outbound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in principle this is possible. This is called asymmetric routing.

For example, this is how satellite home internet works: satellite link is downstream-only, because the household receiver could only receive but not transmit, so a second land-based link is required to send upstream (outbound) packets.

However, it is not simple at all. Think about IP addresses packets will have, note that most ISPs drop egress packets where source IP address is not from their network. So, if you given say 1.1.1.1 from ISP1, and 2.2.2.2 from ISP2, you could receive packets for 2.2.2.2 coming from ISP2, but you couldn't send replies to these packets from 2.2.2.2 via ISP1, because they'll be dropped. You only can send packets from 1.1.1.1 via ISP1, but remote party had sent their data to 2.2.2.2 and expects replies from there; they will not consider anything from 1.1.1.1 by default. The satellite providers solve this issue by using some kind of VPN, not very easy solution and has some other drawbacks.

To precisely answer your question, more information is needed: which peers you use, how they expect you should be set up and how they handle your traffic, which routing hardware you plan to use and so on.

Comment: We simply need this kind of setup because our inbound provider protects us from DDoS attacks. If we also send traffic through them, it's crazy expensive. Which is why we wanted to seperate traffic.

Comment: You doing it wrong. If you ever expose your real (unprotected) IPs to public, you will lose all protection. This is known limitation of CloudFlare and other DDoS-protection services: never connect directly to internet from protected server, always use protection service!